# How to disable and enable the window refresh when click on the top-left app icon?

Tags: c++, mfc, window

How to disable and enable the window refresh when click on the top-left app icon?

For example, in window every .exe has a icon in its top-left sign, when we right click on that icon, some application stop refresh its window(For example, if the applicaiton has text-input, when you left-click on the top-left icon, the cursor in the text-input will stop blink), and for some other application, when you lef-click on the top-left icon, the application window will still refresh, how to enable or disable this?

Any code example is welcome, the question is urgent, please give your help.

Thanks a lost.
Wa

Comment: Mouse cursor painting isn't (usually) managed by the application! It stops to blink because the text box did lost the focus (now on the system menu). Usually applications does **not** stop refreshing when system menu is open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a standard menu behavior implemented with Windows. It's better not to override it as it's really painful. You can also put a a wait logic (using WaitForSingleObject) or Sleep for a while but that will make the application unresponsive.

If you can explain the purpose, we might be able to help you better.